# PowerMock whenNew still going into constructor code

Tags: powermockito

I am trying to get Powermock to work by mocking out a constructor. In the method I am testing a constructor of another class is called (and takes in a lot of params, empty constructor not available). I don't want this constructor to be called as I do not have all the params/values it needs.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({FeatureManager.class, MyFilter.class})
public class ApplicabilityTest {
@Before
    public void setUp() {
PowerMockito.mock(Filter.class);
        MyFilter myFilterMock = PowerMockito.mock(MyFilter.class);
        try {

  PowerMockito.whenNew(MyFilter.class).withAnyArguments()
.thenReturn(MyFilterMock);
}

@Test
public void testAllApplicableStuff() {
    ApplicabilityComponent applicabilityComponent = new ApplicabilityComponent();
    Map response = ApplicabilityComponent.getAllApplicableExclusions(myInputData);
}
```

However, when I call the method where the constructor of myFilter is called, it still goes into the constructor code. What am I missing?

This is what the call to the constructor looks like in the actual code:

```
final MyFilter mFilter = new 
MyFilter(
                        getNames(),
                        getPlaces(),
                        null,
                        provider,
                        procedure,
                        null,
                        new ArrayList(),
                        getServiceCategory(),
                        getCategory(),
                        null,
                        null,
                        getEffectiveDate(),
                        null);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why this work, but this is what I did to fix the problem. I mocked the object with Mockito and not Powermock and the rest then just worked as is:

```
@Before
    public void setUp() {
        MyFilter myFilterMock = Mockito.mock(MyFilter.class);
    try {

  PowerMockito.whenNew(MyFilter.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn(MyFilterMock);
}
```

Comment: Can the MyFilter be Interface and will this mock works for all its implementations ?